# Sharing custom elements between projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, custom-element

I have a react Project (i.e Project1), created using create react app, and would like to wrap one of my components into a web component. In addition, I have a simple vanilla JS project (i.e Project2) which uses iframes to render pages from Project1. I am trying to get rid of the iframe approach and wrap my pages/components from Project1 into web components/custom elements and use them in Project2. So far what I've tried is including the pre-build bundle from Project1 in Project2 but the new custom element did not render. Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you post some code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: `import MealEditFormCE from './custom-component';

const tagName = 'evil-plan';

if (!window.customElements.get(tagName)) {
  // prevent rerunning on hot module reloads
  // register to be rendered in place of every <evil-plan> tag
  window.customElements.define(tagName, MealEditFormCE);
}`

then in Project2

`<script src="path_to_project1_bundle"></script>`

Comment: Start by fixing the **29%**  React does not support in Web Components: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/libraries/react/results/results.html

Comment: Can you share your code snippets?